# Глобализация объектов констант

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть у меня два глобальных объекта. Сейчас они определяются и инициализируются так

```
A a(5);
B b;

int main() {
  ......
```

Теперь я хочу их вынести в отдельный `h` файл и запретить модификацию этих переменных.

Пишу так

```cpp
// globals.h
extern const A a;
extern const B b;
```

```cpp
// globals.cpp
const A a(5);
const B b;
```

Сразу в `h` файле получаю подсказки

> Clang-Tidy: Static variable 'a' may be dynamically initialized in this header file
> Clang-Tidy: Static variable 'b' may be dynamically initialized in this header file

А при попытке использования этих переменных

```cpp
#include "globals.h"

int main () {
  a.setValue(5);
}
```

получаю ошибку

> 'this' argument to member function 'print' has type 'const A', but function is not marked const

Т.е. получается, что я объявил не константную переменную, а переменную, содержащую константный объект

Если `const` убрать, то программа компилируется, но становится возможным переприсвоить этим переменным значение. И Clang-Tidy подсказки никуда не деваются

**Update**

Тут я вижу, что возникло недопонимание. Мне нужно  вызывать неконстантные методы и менять состояние объекта. Я хочу запретить модификацию этих переменных.

Т.е.

```cpp
b.setValue(10);  // OK
B b1;
b = b1;  // Error
```

фактически мою проблему решают функции

```cpp
// globals.h
A getA();
B getB();
```

```cpp
// globals.cpp

A a(5);
B b;

A getA() {
  return a;
}

B getB() {
  return b;
}
```

но хотелось бы без них

**Update2**

Нужен аналог константных указателей

```cpp
A * const a = new A(5);

a->setValue(10);  // OK
a = nullptr;  // Error
```

Comment: Ну, касательно `print`, вам просто нужно добавить `const` к объявлению этого метода.

Comment: а в чём разница между «константной переменной» и «переменной, содержащий константный объект»? ну и про то чтобы сделать метод константным уже сказали...

Comment: Если это просто какая-то не изменяющаяся на протяжении работы программы переменная, то почему бы просто не определить ее как константу?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch как? Я это и пытаюсь сделать

Comment: Какой то борщ у вас, а  желание непонятное.....

Comment: @AntonShchyrov просто объявив константу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы хотите запретить конструкции вида

```
b = b1;  // Error
```

то Вам нужно просто напросто удалить конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания.

```
class A {
public:
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
```

если Вам не повезло и у Вас старый старый компилятор без поддержки с++11 - тогда перемещайте в приватную часть.

Также, возможно, нужно такое же сделать и для конструктора перемещения и оператора. Но тут по надобностям.

Comment: Это запретит вообще любое присваивание объектов этого класса, ну да ладно. Проблему решает

Comment: всегда можно создать специальный класс для конкретной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
public:
void print() const;
};
```

`const` говорит о том, что метод может использовать константный объект. И при этом поля нельзя изменять.

Comment: Это легкая половина вопроса, а вот почему clang-tidy дает ворнинг...

Comment: Мне нужно  вызывать неконстантные методы и менять состояние объекта. Я хочу запретить модификацию этих переменных

Comment: @AntonShchyrov изменение полей в объекте - это и есть его модификация. А то что вы хотите сделать - это полный бред. Либо const либо не const.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Так не бывает. Модификация - это и есть вызов неконстантных методов (а также запись в поля).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А для указателей бывает? `A * const a;`. И никто это бредом не считает

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Для указатей да, но у вас-то не указатель.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Т.е. в с++ такое ограничение добавить невозможно?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А что именно вы хотите запретить? Присваивание `a = ...;`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  где то определен не константный объект.  extern const A a; находит только его, а он не константный.  Вот и почему clang-tidy дает ворнинг.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Да. Причем желательно для конкретной переменной, а не любых объектов этого класса

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Смотрите, когда вы пишете `a = ...;`, и `a` - это объект класса, то это просто сокращенная запись для `a.operator=(...);`. Оператор присваивания - это такой же метод, как и все остальные, поэтому и нельзя просто так запретить присваивание, а остальные неконстнатные методы не трогать.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я сейчас удалил все `const`. Более того, переименовал переменную в `aThisUnique`. Ворнинг остался

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ясно. Просто в остальных языках всякие `const`, `final` блокируют именно присваивание

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Видимо это в тех языках, где объекты классов всегда являются ссылками/указателями, поэтому там это имеет смысл.

Comment: Так компилятор хочет найти определение, а его  нет. Не пишите так, да и все дела _ сразу определите как статический.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Чего нет? Я в `h` файле объявляю переменные. В `cpp` их определяю. В чем криминал?

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, В C++ переменная const имеет внутреннюю связь по умолчанию. В остальном долго объяснять что почему и как...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ключевые слова и операции имеют разный смысл в разных языках. По сравнению со всякими java / javascript в С++ присваивание не означает ребиндинг ссылки, а собственно операция ребиндинга ссылки в языке отсутствует. То бишь ссылочные типы в С++ всегда как бы final в смысле java.